# What is the difference between SOT143 and SOT143B?

Tags: packages

I have a component whose package is defined as SOT143B, and in my layout package a footprint described as SOT143. I am having trouble finding out what the difference might be. At a guess, package height?

Comment: The manufacturer of the component should have a document with the footprint in it. If not, try contacting them. Anyway, the one in your PCB package should be suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used them interchangeably before - I believe they are identical as far as footprint in concerned. The internals of the packaging may be different, but from the point of view of laying out a PCB there is no difference.